# How we can override the Edit and Detailed page with the Custom VF Page?

Tags: custom-object

How to override the edit functionality to custom edit page and detailed page ?

The below is the related list of the Case object, when I click on Edit, then Custom VF Edit page should open and when click on then I want to display the detailed page how we can do that ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You configure this in the **Button, Links and Actions** section of your object in Salesforce Setup.

Salesforce has a great [guide](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=links_customize_override.htm&type=0) on the exact steps but the important requirement for your Visualforce page is that it uses the `StandardController` for the object you are trying to override an action or link for.